# Silverstripe URL Mapping

Tags: silverstripe, url-mapping, url-masking

I'm trying to understand how URL Mapping works.  I've gone through numerous pages, but I can't seem to wrap my head around what I'm trying to do.

Its really simple, I use DataObjects as pages approach and I have a member extension written to the member class.  And I have the typical actions, show, edit, add.

So if I go to www.mywebsite.com/members/show/1 I can see the first user.  If I change show to edit, I can edit the first user.  Now if I go to www.mywebsite.com/members/add I can create a new user.  This is working all as expected due to the functionality I created in the add method.

My problem is in the fact that when you go any website, you don't register to the website by going to members/add, you register by going to website.com/Register or something similar.  From code management perspective, it is a lot easier for me to leave the code the way it is now.  I don't want to have to create a Register page and move the code there, instead I am trying to figure out if it is possible to go to www.mywebsite.com/Register and have it load www.mywebsite.com/members/add.  I am not talking about a redirect link that would update the url, I want users to still see Register in the url and not see /members/add.

Vice versa, if users were to go to www.mywebsite.com/members/add I want the link to update to Register or say page not found.

Is this possible with Silverstripe Framework?

I am not 100% sure, but I believe this is called URL Masking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very possible, firstly I'd advise that you look over...

[silverstripe-memberprofiles](https://github.com/silverstripe-australia/silverstripe-memberprofiles)

...because even if you dont' want to use an existing module I'm sure there would be useful information.  There is a great example of "pure" routing (i.e. silverstripe no cms) that leads on to "nested" routes - which is what I think you are asking for, so I highly recommend reading the slides below and then the created todo app

[silverstripe-framework-building-without-the-cms](http://www.slideshare.net/DanielHensby/silverstripe-framework-building-without-the-cms)

[todo app source](https://github.com/dhensby/todo-list/tree/master/www/mysite)

Comment: I've gone through that module before, I chose not to use it because I learn better by making my own.  The other problem was because that module is so vast and there are so many things happening it will take me weeks to dig through and find what I'm looking for.  Is there a link to a guide that you can give me or you yourself explain me how routing/masking works with silverstripe?

Comment: I assume you are talking about the first link, did you look through the second / third link?  This shows with a simple todo application but with nested routing logic. If you just want the docs for routing... https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.2/developer_guides/controllers/routing/

Comment: Hi, the second link is blocked for me as I'm at work at the moment and cannot view it, I will go over it tonight.  The third link is completely broken and doesn't work when I click on it.

Comment: I've updated the third link (still getting used to stack overflow syntax!)